# c++ compiler version in unix

Tags: c++, unix

I want to know the compiler version (CC) of a server under unix environment. Apparently i find the correct directory where the compiler is installed

```
    cngsitbe1a@/opt/SUNWspro/prod/bin$ ls -ltr
    total 82225
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        22864 Apr 30  2007 libsunperf_check
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys      1193036 May  3  2007 acomp
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys       480752 May  3  2007 fbe
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys      8298296 May  3  2007 cg
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys      6454044 May  3  2007 iropt
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys      5294740 May  3  2007 ccfe
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys       534392 May  3  2007 CClink
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys       116212 May  3  2007 c++filt
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        18580 May  3  2007 stdlibfilt
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys       539124 May  3  2007 CCadmin
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys         7408 May  3  2007 dem
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys          519 May  3  2007 ptclean
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        30936 May  3  2007 cb
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        16004 May  3  2007 nmf
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        19216 May  3  2007 lpfx
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        14944 May  3  2007 flip
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        17172 May  3  2007 dag
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys         5118 May  3  2007 cflow
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys       101484 May  3  2007 cscope
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys         8920 May  3  2007 runtime.c
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        63004 May  3  2007 ctrace
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys         3361 May  3  2007 ctcr
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        21788 May  3  2007 xref
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys         4863 May  3  2007 cxref
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys        11508 May  3  2007 irprint
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys       358548 May  3  2007 CC
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys       246684 May  3  2007 lint
    -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     sys       276584 May  3  2007 cc
```

However, when I use the command to find CC version, no useful info is given.

```
    cngsitbe1a@/opt/SUNWspro/prod/bin$ CC -V
    -bash: CC: command not found
```

Also, when a binary is compiled in server A and deployed/run in server B, does the compiler of server B affect the triggering of binary? Can help?

Comment: You should use `./CC -V`

Comment: `$CC --version` (if the environment variable CC is set) or `cc --version`

Comment: Why would the compiler of server B affect the triggering of binary? The binary is already compiled.

Comment: ok, seems working. Thanks for the help! But when i use CC -V on another server it works..

Comment: Probably because `CC` is found through that server's system path. Run `echo $PATH` to see which directories are searched through to find binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
./CC -V
```

to call the `CC` executable, as long `/opt/SUNWspro/prod/bin` isn't part of your `PATH` variable.

---

As mentioned in comments, most compilers use the `--version` option to retrieve the current version.

Comment: `-V` is not a valid option of gcc. For the version, use `--version`

Comment: @Boiethios Sure this is a GCC installaton?

Comment: Perhaps clang, but it is same for it: `clang --version`

Comment: Anyways, that wasn't actually in question.

Comment: @Boiethios I think that is a side issue, the main issue is the lack of `./` or that `/opt/SUNWspro/prod/bin` is missing from the system path.

Comment: That is true… Then a good solution would be to install the compiler in a directory from `PATH`.

Comment: This is of course, _not_ GCC at all, nor even the second guess of Clang.  It is, as the directory name outright tells us, the compiler from Sun Workshop, now known as Oracle Developer Studio.